# Heroku 500 internal server error undefined method 'username' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app is able to run on my local server just fine, but when I pushed it from git to heroku it's not working on heroku. I've run heroku run rake db:migrate, but still no luck. I'm guessing it has something to do with the username method, but not sure why it would work on my local and not on heroku.

```
2013-03-01T05:45:00+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <% if current_user == pin.user %>
2013-03-01T05:45:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_pins_index_html_erb__3245926179851309408_37549160'
2013-03-01T05:45:00+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2013-03-01T05:45:00+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 99.190.128.33 at 2013-03-01 05:45:01 +0000
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as HTML
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=railsapp-                     test.herokuapp.com fwd="99.190.128.33" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=0ms service=38ms   status=500 bytes
=643
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/_home.html.erb (3.7ms)
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (11.3ms)
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application (20.5ms)
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:            <strong>
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:                    Posted by <%= pin.user.username  %>
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/_pin.html.erb:8:in  `_app_views_pins__pin_html_erb___1817132116748238264_25273940'
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/index.html.erb:4:in  `_app_views_pins_index_html_erb__3245926179851309408_37549160'
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:8:in `index'
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 22ms
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `username'  for nil:NilClass):
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:    </p>
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:    <p>
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:            </strong>
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <% if current_user == pin.user %>
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   </p>
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:01+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 99.190.128.33 at 2013-03-01 05:45:02  +0000
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as HTML
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/_home.html.erb (4.4ms)
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application  (22.2ms)
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:    <p>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `username'  for nil:NilClass):
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[we
b.1]:   app/views/pins/_pin.html.erb:8:in  `_app_views_pins__pin_html_erb___1817132116748238264_25273940'
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:8:in `index'
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <% if current_user == pin.user %>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:                    Posted by <%= pin.user.username  %>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (12.4ms)
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   </p>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:    </p>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/index.html.erb:4:in  `_app_views_pins_index_html_erb__3245926179851309408_37549160'
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:            <strong>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:            </strong>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 99.190.128.33 at 2013-03-01 05:45:02 +0000
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as HTML
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/_home.html.erb (1.6ms)
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=railsapp- test.herokuapp.com fwd="99.190.128.33" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=3ms connect=2ms service=63ms  status=500 bytes
=643
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:                    Posted by <%= pin.user.username  %>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:    </p>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:    <p>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (47.0ms)
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:            <strong>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application  (50.3ms)
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <% if current_user == pin.user %>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/_pin.html.erb:8:in  `_app_views_pins__pin_html_erb___1817132116748238264_25273940'
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:8:in `index'
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:            </strong>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/index.html.erb:4:in  `_app_views_pins_index_html_erb__3245926179851309408_37549160'
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   </p>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `username'  for nil:NilClass):
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 99.190.128.33 at 2013-03-01 05:45:02    +0000
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as HTML
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/_home.html.erb (2.8ms)
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/index.html.erb within layouts/application  (12.7ms)
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/_pin.html.erb (8.0ms)
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `username'  for nil:NilClass):
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:    </p>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:    <p>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:                    Posted by <%= pin.user.username %>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:            </strong>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/_pin.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_pins__pin_html_erb___1817132116748238264_25273940'
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <% if current_user == pin.user %>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   </p>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:            <strong>
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=railsapp- test.herokuapp.com fwd="99.190.128.33" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=3ms service=22ms  status=500 bytes
=643
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/index.html.erb:4:in   `_app_views_pins_index_html_erb__3245926179851309408_37549160'
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:8:in `index'
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2013-03-01T05:45:02+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=railsapp-test.herokuapp.com fwd="99.190.128.33" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=32ms status=500 bytes
=643
```

EDIT: Here is the code under pins_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(params[:pin])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.save
        format.html { redirect_to pins_path, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @pin, status: :created, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: So you've run rake db:migrate but is there any data in it? Try creating a user and see if thats part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your username method is fine - the problem is caused by your pin instance not having a user (i.e. pin.user is nil). When saving the pin, make sure a user is correctly assigned.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, but can you explain how I can assign a user. Since the site won't go up, how does a user sign up?

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you need to create the Pin(s) that you are displaying in your index action (I assume this is PinsController#create). There, you need to have something like pin.user = current_user. Prerequisite: your Pin table needs to have a user_id column and in the Pin model, you need to define the has_a :user association. It would help if you would post your PinsController#create action.

Comment: So I ran heroku db:push and that solved it. I guess I need to study up more on how to look at the database from console, Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, but I doubt that `heroku db:push` really solved your issue. It just copied your local db to heroku. In your local db, you might not have this issue, but somehow, in the heroku db, a pin without an associated user was created. So tackling the root cause, you need to find out how a pin could be created without reference to a user.