# Only getting NilClass error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm getting an error in my heroku logs, but everything is working fine locally. Any ideas?

```
The error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass)
```

I just have this little method in my user.rb.

```
  def full_name
    return first_name + " " + last_name
  end
```

And here's the heroku log:

```
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 98.222.28.137 at 2013-03-05 05:34:54 +0000
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=objecss.herokuapp.com fwd="98.222.28.137" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=73ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by EntriesController#index as HTML
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered entries/_entries.html.erb (7.7ms)
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:           <%=  link_to "Users", users_path %>
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:   <% if current_user  %>
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered entries/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.5ms)
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/entries_controller.rb:9:in `index'
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:21:in `full_name'
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2449026742642080137_44886800'
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:       <% if admin? %>
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:       <%= link_to "#{current_user.full_name}", current_user %>
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <%= link_to "Objecss", entries_path %>
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:     10: <div class="utility">
2013-03-05T05:34:54+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:       <%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path("current"), method: "delete" %>
```

Comment: I found a related question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151792/heroku-500-internal-server-error-undefined-method-username-for-nilnilclass?rq=1

Are the answers there relevant to my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by first name and last name not being set for this particular user. Just open the rails console on heroku and assign first name and last name for that user. You can do something like this

```
[56] pry(main)> u=User.find(1)
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
[58] pry(main)> u.first_name = "John"
=> "John"
[59] pry(main)> u.last_name = "Doe"
=> "Doe"
[60] pry(main)> u.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = 'example' AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (1.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "first_name" = 'John', "last_name" = 'Doe', "updated_at" = '2013-03-05 06:01:55.263347' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
   (24.5ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

Comment: That was it. First and last name was empty. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass)

This is telling you that the return value of `first_name` is `nil`; There is no `+` method defined on `NilClass`, thus the error.

Simply put, the instance of `User` you're working with on Heroku has no `first_name` set.